# How to minimize an X-window on a low-level (not wmctrl or xdotool)?

Tags: x11

There are quite some X tools by default installed on a modern OS such as Ubuntu. According to the `man` pages there is `xprop`, `xdpyinfo`, `xwininfo`, `xdriinfo`, `glxinfo` and `nvinfo`.

For example, it seems to be the case that I can set:

```
xprop -id $id -f _NET_WM_STATE 32a -set _NET_WM_STATE "_NET_WM_ACTION_MINIMIZE"
```

Here `a` as according to the manual corresponds with the "atom" property.

However, this doesn't seem to work. Am I perhaps setting only a property and doesn't it actually get updated? And in that case, how can I enforce the latter?

A more complete script so you can test yourself, suppose we have started chrome with the `-maximized` flag and want to minimize it later on:

```
#!/bin/bash

search=chrome
filter=maximized

findpid=$(ps aux | grep $search | grep $filter | tr -s '  ' ' ' | cut -f2 -d' ')

# pick only one pid
findpid=$(echo $findpid | cut -f1 -d' ')
echo "Search for window with pid=$findpid"

known_windows=$(xwininfo -root -children|sed -e 's/^ *//'|grep -E "^0x"|awk '{ print $1 }')

for id in ${known_windows}
do
    xp=$(xprop -id $id _NET_WM_PID)
    if test $? -eq 0; then
        pid=$(xprop -id $id _NET_WM_PID|cut -d'=' -f2|tr -d ' ')

        if test "x${pid}" = x${findpid}
        then
            echo "Windows Id: $id"
            xprop -id $id 
            xprop -id $id -f _NET_WM_STATE 32a -set _NET_WM_STATE "_NET_WM_ACTION_MINIMIZE"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Maybe I should use something different than `xprop`, but `xset` etc seem not to be on the level of the individual windows themselves.

Answer (score 2):

`_NET_WM_ACTION_MINIMIZE` is an atom used to indicate "can be maximized" flag in a list of window's supported actions. To ask for action, you send `_NET_WM_STATE` client message to a *root* window and emwh-compliant WM would perform action for you, see http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html#idm140130317598336

To un-maximise, you set `_NET_WM_STATE_REMOVE` as action and send message with `_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_VERT` as first property and `_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_HORIZ` as second property.

Comment: Something like `xprop -root -f _NET_WM_STATE 32a -set _NET_WM_STATE '_NET_WM_STATE_REMOVE, _NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_VERT, _NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_HORIZ, 1'` doesn't actually un-maximize a window. It only sets the `_NET_WM_STATE` field of the root window. Is my syntax incorrect or do I need to inform the wm to actually apply this action?

Comment: You need to send a message, not just set window property

Comment: also, not all WMs have full support for ewmh protocol. You can test some features support using https://github.com/joewing/wmtest

Comment: Nice code, but what I understand from this is that it is either using `wmctrl` or roll your own code. And that there is no way to send messages from the command-line using `xprop` or another utility that's installed by default.

Comment: I wrote simple command line utility to send _NET_WM_STATE message - https://github.com/sidorares/xclimsg